# Arranging the letter COMMITTEE when it has to begin and end with a vowel?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can the letter COMMITTEE be arranged when it has to begin and end with a vowel?

I tried to use 4P2 * 7!/ (2!)**3, but 4P2/ 2! (=6) does not solve the arrangements of vowels, O,I,E,E, which are OI,OE,IO,IE,EO,EI,EE (7). So, is there a formula for that?

Comment: It's inelegant, but if I were doing this problem under any time pressure, I would just consider the $7$ disjoint possibilities you describe and then compute the number of arrangments of the remaining letters in the usual way.

Answer (score 3):

W/o restrictions, permutations $=\frac{9!}{2!2!2!} = 45360$

Fraction of permutations with vowels at either end = $\frac49\frac38 = \frac16$

Thus valid arrangements $= \frac16\cdot45360 =7560$

Comment: +1 : Forced me to eat my words, about forgoing elegance.

Comment: @user2661923: Glad you like it !

Comment: Thanks a lot, that’s a beautiful method. Although I have a little bit difficulty to understand how to determine the fraction of permutations with vowels. Can you pls kindly explain a little more on this?

Comment: @LeoYT For the choice of the first letter, $(4)$ out of $(9)$ of the letters are vowels.  Therefore, at random, $\frac{4}{9}$ of the $\displaystyle S = \frac{9!}{(2!)(2!)(2!)}$ possible sequences begin with a vowel.  Similarly, under the assumption that all of the sequences are eliminated except the $\frac{4}{9} \times S$ sequences that begin with a vowel, there are then $(8)$ letters left, of which $(3)$ of them are vowels, for the choice of satisfying sequences that both begin and end with vowels.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it now. ♥️

Comment: You're welcome ! Using probabilities in permutation questions is often a nice shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

I agree completely with the comment of Charles Hudgins, that
it is best to forgo any attempt at elegance.  **Highjacking**
his idea:

Each of the 5 possibilities 
OxxxxxxxE 
ExxxxxxxO 
IxxxxxxxE 
ExxxxxxxI 
ExxxxxxxE

will result in the remaining letters 
MMTTCxy, where x,y are distinct letters.

Each of the 5 possibilities above may therefore be permuted in 
$\displaystyle N_1 = \frac{7!}{(2!)\times (2!)}~$ ways.

---

The two remaining possibilities 
OxxxxxxxI 
IxxxxxxxO

will result in the remaining letters 
MMTTCEE.

Each of the 2 possibilities above may therefore be permuted in 
$\displaystyle N_2 = \frac{7!}{(2!)\times (2!) \times (2!)}~$ ways.

---

Final computation:

$$(5 \times N_1) + (2 \times N_2).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I totally understand it.